# Select query dynamic column QUOTENAME MAX aggregate function

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have dynamic query to show output `DISTINCT` using `MAX()` aggregate function fields.

```
DECLARE @var1 NVARCHAR(20)
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(255)

SET @var1 = '2018' -- this is the dynamic column, it will produce 2018, 2019, 2020 and so on
SET @sql = 'select MAX(ID) AS ColID, MAX(Name) AS ColName, ' + QUOTENAME(@var1, 'MAX()') + ' from [Table] GROUP BY ColID'

EXEC sp_executesql @stmt = @sql
```

but, I get an error:

> Column 'Table.2018' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place the variable column into the max function:

```
SET @sql = '
select
  MAX(ID) AS ColID,
  MAX(Name) AS ColName,
  MAX(' + QUOTENAME(@var1) + ')
from [Table]
GROUP BY ColID
'
```